# Disable App Center Push in UWP

Tags: push-notification, uwp, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I have integrated the [Microsoft App Center](https://appcenter.ms) push notification feature in one of my UWP apps. Now I'd like to let the user decide if he wants to receive push notifications or not.

According to the SDK I can [Enable or disable App Center Push at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/uwp#enable-or-disable-app-center-push-at-runtime), but this will not actually disable anything...

> disabling the App Center Push in the SDK will NOT stop your application from receiving push notifications.

So, is there even anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Can't seem to find the exact solution but would like to offer the following workarounds:

- App Center allows to create Audiences to target different segments of app users when sending push notifications. You could create an Audience for those who don't want to receive push notifications and simply avoid them when sending the pushes.
- There's [a way to unregister for push notifications sent from Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/configure-your-app-to-receive-dev-center-notifications). If you used the later instead of App Center to send notifications your problem would be solved.
- To get pushes from App Center it's required that an app calls `AppCenter.Start(...)` method on start-up. What if it doesn't?

Comment: Alough App Center has not provide a method for you to stop receiving notifications. But you could launch the windows settings to let users set against receiving notifications from your app. await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:notifications"));